# Copying strings from vector is not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy a word to a file if that word does not contain a vowel. This is my attempt, but it's not working. It copies the words to the file but it doesn't exclude the words with vowels. I'm not sure why it outputs what it does anyway...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename It>
bool has_vowel(It begin, It end)
{
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        char lower = std::tolower(*it);

        if (lower == 'a' || lower == 'e' ||
            lower == 'i' || lower == 'o' || lower == 'u')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::fstream in("in.txt");
    std::fstream out("out.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string str;

    while (in >> str)
    {
        v.push_back(str);
    }

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!has_vowel(it->begin(), it->end()))
            out << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

in.txt

> Hello my friends and family

output to out.txt

> myllofriendsandfamily

Comment: `if (!callback(it))` should be `if (!callback(*it))`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/MEZY3k

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah I did a mistype.

Comment: The output I am getting to out.txt is `myllofriendsandfamily` and not `my` as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're feeling masochistic, it's almost certainly a lot easier to code up the vowel-check using `find_first_of`:

```
struct has_vowel { 
    bool operator()(std::string const &a) { 
        static const std::string vowels("aeiouAEIOU");

        return a.find_first_of(vowels) != std::string::npos;
    }
};
```

When you want to copy some container, but exclude items that meet a condition, you generally want to use `std::remove_copy_if`. Since this can work directly with `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator` you don't need to store all the words in a vector while you do the job either:

```
std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, " "),
                    has_vowel());
```

If you're willing to use C++11, you can use a lambda for the condition:

```
std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, " "),
                    [](std::string const &s) { 
                        return s.find_first_of("aeiouAEIOU") != std::string::npos;
                    });
```

Comment: I think you forgot the fourth parameter to `remove_copy_if` that takes the callback.

Comment: You also forgot the closing angle bracket to `ostream_iterator` lol

Comment: You have a parenthesis `)` after `std::string::npos` that doesn't belong also. I will accept though, thanks! :)

Comment: @MemyselfandI: One of these years I really need to learn how to type (or at least proofread).

Answer (score 3):

---Use `noskipws`---

Actually that was a thinko. Here's a minimal rework using C++11. I hope you can glean something useful from this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename It>
bool has_vowel(It begin, It end)
{
    while (begin!=end)
    {
        char lower = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(*begin));

        if (lower == 'a' || lower == 'e' ||
            lower == 'i' || lower == 'o' || lower == 'u')
            return true;

        ++begin;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> f(std::cin), l;

    for (auto& s : std::vector<std::string>(f, l))
    {
        if (!has_vowel(s.begin(), s.end()))
            std::cout << s << " ";
    }
}
```

See it live: **http://ideone.com/1tYfs2**

Alternatively, avoiding the vector:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> f(std::cin), l;

    for_each(f, l, [] (std::string const& s) {
            if (!has_vowel(s.begin(), s.end()))
                std::cout << s << " ";
        });
}
```

Comment: @MemyselfandI Mmm. There must be something different from the code you posted :/ Glad I could get you on the trail of `skipws`. As a bonus, please see my C++11 version. C++11 rocks!

Comment: Added a variation that avoids the temporary storage (i.e. is _streaming_) without getting quite so _terse_ as Jerry's answer /cc @JerryCoffin

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the output file incorrectly. `std::fstream` will not discard the old content of the file. Use `std::ofstream` instead.

Comment: Good catch. I subconsciously noticed that, but I manually cleared the file. I'll remember this! Honestly, I think this was the real issue.